# Deployed war to tomcat can't throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException

Tags: persistence, tomcat6, derby, persistence.xml

I'm new to this forum and also new to JPA / EJB.

I'm trying to deploy a .war file containing a small application to a tomcat server. The application is using JTA to communicate with the Derby db.

When I run and deploy the application from and eclipse top the tomcat server running in eclipse, everything works perfect, but when I export a .war file and try to browse the application it throws an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException.

My persistence file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="lab1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->
        <class>entity.Team</class>
        <class>entity.Gambler</class>
        <class>entity.Bet</class>
        <class>entity.Game</class>
        <class>entity.Gameday</class>
          <properties>
       <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hean0901;create=true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName"  value="lab1"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="user"/>
            <property name="lab1.log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE"/>
            <property name="nonTransactionalDataSource" value="true"/> 
            <!-- <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>-->
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and the error thrown looks like this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 1

1: <jsp:forward page="Setupcheck.do" />


Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:706)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:677)
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:54)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
 model.Setupcheck.processRequest(Setupcheck.java:31)
 model.Setupcheck.doGet(Setupcheck.java:43)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:706)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:677)
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:54)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
 model.Setupcheck.processRequest(Setupcheck.java:31)
 model.Setupcheck.doGet(Setupcheck.java:43)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:706)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:677)
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:54)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Best regards
Henrik

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be missing the javax.persistence.PersistenceException class (part of the JPA spec).

The Java Persistence API JAR (containing the PersistenceException class) can be found here :

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/persistence-api-1.0.jar

This JAR needs to be in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Depending on how you've setup your Eclipse, it probably pushed these JARs to Tomcat automatically (by defining a library).

However, the fact that it tries to load the PersistenceException most likely means that another exception (the real exception) will occur once you solve this ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: In addition to packaging the JPA libraries in your war file, make sure that you are packaging the necessary Derby jars in your war file. In your case, it looks like you'll need derbyclient.jar there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven for managing project dependencies, then including the following in my `pom.xml` worked for me:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```