# ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, libs

I'm getting this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

This is my project:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
   <persistence-unit name="Forum">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
           <class>Model.Section</class>
               <properties>
                   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                   <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Forum" />
                   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
                   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
               </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

NewSectionController.java

```
package Controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import Model.Section;

public class NewSectionController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NewSectionController() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("newSection.jsp");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String title = request.getParameter("titulo");
        String description = request.getParameter("descricao");
        Section section = new Section();
        section.insertNewSection(title, description);
    }

}
```

Section.java

package Model;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

@Entity
public class Section {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int idSection;
    @Column
    String titleSection;
    @Column
    String descriptionSection;

    public void insertNewSection(String title, String description) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Forum");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        Section section = new Section();
        section.setTitleSection(title);
        section.setDescriptionSection(description);

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(section);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public int getIdSection() {
        return idSection;
    }
    public void setIdSection(int idSection) {
        this.idSection = idSection;
    }
    public String getTitleSection() {
        return titleSection;
    }
    public void setTitleSection(String titleSection) {
        this.titleSection = titleSection;
    }
    public String getDescriptionSection() {
        return descriptionSection;
    }
    public void setDescriptionSection(String descriptionSection) {
        this.descriptionSection = descriptionSection;
    }
}
```

The files are organized this way:

```
src/Controller/NewSectionController.java
src/Model/Section.java
src/META-INF/persistence.xml
resources/log4j.properties
lib/
WebContent/
```

And I have imported and add to build path all these libs:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
hibernate-c3p0-4.2.2.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.2.2.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.2.2.Final.jar
hibernate-infinispan-4.2.2.Final-tests.jar
hibernate-infinispan-4.2.2.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-proxool-4.2.2.Final.jar
infinispan-core-5.2.0.Beta3.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar
jboss-marshalling-1.3.15.GA.jar
jboss-marshalling-river-1.3.15.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jgroups-3.2.0.CR1.jar
proxool-0.8.3.jar
rhq-pluginAnnotations-3.0.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar
```

And I'm still getting the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence error.

What should I do?

Comment: seems to be missing persistence api

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541893/deployed-war-to-tomcat-cant-throws-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-persis

Comment: try to specify `@Transient` to your method `insertNewSection`